# Changing colour of angularjs slider with pointer

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Hi I'm building a slider in angularjs that changes color depending on where you move the pointer.

1.) if the pointer is on the rightside, the bar will be red
2.) if the pointer is on the leftside, the bar will be blue 
3.)If the pointer is in the middle the bar will be half red, half blue

I am using this library: http://prajwalkman.github.io/angular-slider/

Problem:

I'm trying to accomplish this by having one pointer to be fixed on the bottom and invisible so that there is only one pointer moving while the slider changes color.  However i'm scratching my head on how to make this work.  Any help?

Here is a plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/tmDfTksDwSRLrc0choOJ?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked your code, It has nothing to do with angular js, you just need to modify the css in angular-slider.css on line 19 for accomplishing this.

```
slider span.bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1em/1em;
  border-radius: 1em/1em;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #F53337), color-stop(1, #F72529));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F53337 0, #F72529 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F53337 0, #F72529 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F53337 0, #F72529 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F53337 0, #F72529 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #F53337 0, #F72529 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px;
}
```

Here's the plunk : http://plnkr.co/edit/1zjfNbUSwNkdWxpYGZgP?p=preview

Also colors can be adjusted to your taste.

Comment: The problem with this method is that it extends the slider and hides one end from the screen.  Is there a solution where you don't do that.

Comment: Edit: You mean the width is set to 4522px,check inline style set it to whatever width of slider you require. Better will be inspect element and adjust slider according to your needs